# How to skip particular WebElement process when locator is not found?

Tags: selenium

```
prinBalAgencyComm.sendKeys(testData.get("agencyCommissionPB"));

prinBalClientRem.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

prinBalFrom2.sendKeys(testData.get("fromFB2")); //Locator not found

prinBalAgencyCommLast.sendKeys(testData.get("agencyCommissionLastPB")); //how to execute this line without fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by using try catch finally.

```
try{
    //code that can result in an exception
    prinBalAgencyComm.sendKeys(testData.get("agencyCommissionPB"));
    prinBalClientRem.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    prinBalFrom2.sendKeys(testData.get("fromFB2"));
}catch(Exception e)
{   
    //actions you want to take in case your locator isnt found or another exception occurs
    System.out.println("Exception occured" + e.getMessage());
}finally
{   //the line to be executed without fail
    prinBalAgencyCommLast.sendKeys(testData.get("agencyCommissionLastPB"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to implement a try/catch block

```
try {
element action
} catch (Exception e) {
//whatever you want to happen when it fails
}`
```

But I would ask myself why is the test not consistent with every run? Why should this step not pass every time?

Answer (score -1):

One pattern you can use is:

```
try {}
catch {}
```

Place your offending code in the `try` block and any error code in the `catch` block.

If an exception is raised in the `try`, the `catch` block will be called instead of proceeding to the next line in the `try`